# TeamCity not building Cordova project when building PhoneGap project

Tags: xcode, cordova, teamcity

I'm trying to build a PhoneGap application using TeamCity and am receiving an error stating that:

AppDelegate.h:30:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

My xcodeproj actually has the Cordova.xcodeproj file inside the project rather than referencing it from anywhere else.  I can tell it is in fact building the project as when I deliberately put in a syntax error into one of its files the build fails on that file, however it doesn't seem like the compiled output is being picked up by the main project.

I can build the project fine through xcode.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Which version of TeamCity are you using?